# Webpack 4: How to call a global function with arguments?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing a new build script for my project using Webpack 4, so far, I have not faced any issue until today, when I have to call a global function with parameters.

Below is an example, I did without parameters for Google reCaptcha:

```
const enableFormButton = () => {
    var elements = "#form_submit_btn, #form_submit_btn_alt";
    $(elements).removeAttr("disabled");
    $(elements).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
    $(elements).removeClass("button button-3d button-red button-small").addClass("button button-3d button-green-invert button-small");
}

const recaptcha = document.querySelectorAll(".g-recaptcha");
recaptcha.forEach((captcha) => {
    captcha.setAttribute('data-callback', 'enableFormButton');
});

export { enableFormButton }
```

and in my entry index.js file, it would look like this:

```
import {enableFormButton} from './some_js_file'
window.enableFormButton = enableFormButton
```

Now, this is what I tried with a global function with parameters:

```
const exampleFunction = (arg1) => {
// do something here
}

export {exampleFunction}
```

and in the index.js file:

```
import {exampleFunction} from './some_js_file'
window.exampleFunction = exampleFunction
```

I tried it, there are no build errors but I get an error in the console saying

> "Uncaught TypeError: exampleFunction is not a function"

Any idea on how to solve this? Btw, I'm kind of new to using Webpack.

Comment: The whole idea of using Webpack is for modules to have explicit dependencies on other modules (which helps avoid global pollution) - if you need a shared function, *import it*. While you *could* define a global function by assigning to `window`, that kind of defeats the purpose of using Webpack in the first place, I would think

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hmm, I'm kinda new to this stuff, so I'm trying to understand as much as I can. :)

Comment: An off-topic suggestion, you might consider creating the `elements` jQuery collection *once*, rather than re-creating it every time. eg `$elements = $(elements);` and then use `$elements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CertainPerformance's tip, I added the `export` keyword to the function `exampleFunction(arg1)`, which should look like this:

```
export exampleFunction(arg1){
   // something
}
```

Imported the function to another .js file:

```
import {exampleFunction} from './somescript';
```

And then, it worked! :)

So turns out, I learnt something for the day!